# Control the origin of images in an SWT browser

Tags: java, browser, swt

I'm programming a desktop application using SWT and I use the browser in parts of the interface because of the flexibility.

I easily can introduce external images. An image in the file system:

```
<img src="/home/user/image.jpg" />
```

Or an image on the web:

```
<img src="http://some.cl/image.jpg" />
```

Can I obtain the images from a stream? In some place of my code I want to program something like this:

```java
OutputSteam getExternaResource(String resourcePath)
```

I want to arbitrarily control the origin of the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a direct way to do this, all I can think of is using javascript to set the image data as base64 string into the `src` of the image.
Using `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.execute(String)` or maybe use `org.eclipse.swt.browser.BrowserFunction`.

The images should have an id which can be used in javascript:

```
<img id="image1" />
```

Edit: on the other hand, maybe it's easier to just parse the HTML previously and set the image base64 string there.

Depending on how you get the HTML you could do:

1. if you create the HTML yourself, just use `<img src="data:image/png;base64....` convert the image to base64 and put it in the `src` attribute
2. if you read the HTML from an external source, you could use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML and replace the image `src` attribute with a base64 string. afterwards use `Browser.setText(String)` to set the HTML of the browser, be aware that in that case relative paths (in links or images) don't work.

   ```
   String html = "html";
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
   Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
   for (Element element : img) {
       String src = element.attr("src");
       // READ image using the existing src, convert to base64 (using java.util.Base64) 
       String base64 = ""; 
       element.attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+);
   }
   String newHtml = doc.html();
   browser.setText(newHtml);
   ```

Comment: It seem like a good idea, but I have to hack a couple of javascript libraries. Maybe is no that difficult , I gona think about.

Comment: Yes,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme .  But in my program I use the markdown library , then I have to change the code of the library to instead of adding a image add that code

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML page, i.e. it is generated by your code, possibly from a template, then you can embed the image.

The bytes of the image need to be base64 encoded and appended to the `src` attribute of the `image` tag like described here: http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/